# Obter usuário logado no Django de forma global

Tags: django, django-queryset

Todas as minhas *models* tem relacionamento com o `User`, e por *default* todas as minhas `query_set` serão feitas com base no usuário logado no sistema. Como faria para obter o usuário logado em qualquer área do app, por exemplo a *model*, porque nela irei criar meu `objectManager` para trazer a *query* por usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não resolve o seu problema se nas views você utilizar o `request.user` quando estiver fazendo as queries?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o `request.user` disponível na `view` que carrega a página.

Veja mais sobre a utilização da autenticação e usuários em:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests

Se quiser saber mais a respeito sobre o `request.user` em específico:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Answer (score 0):

Como exibir o nome do usuário logado em um sistema/site utilizando Django 1.7+.

Basta colocar no template (página html) a linha abaixo para exibir o nome completo:

{{ user.get_full_name }}
Para exibir o username:

{{ user.get_username }}
Para mais informações acesse:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/